# Не работает валидация при ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal

Валидация заработала. Не знаю правильно ли всё. Но пашет

```
/**
 * Access callback for user account editing.
 */
function usertwiks_edit_access($account) {
  return (($GLOBALS['user']->uid == $account->uid) || user_access('administer users')) && $account->uid > 0;
}


function usertwiks_menu(){
   $items = array();

   $items['user/%user/edit/socnet'] = array(
      'title' => 'Подтверждение ',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('usertwiks_form_soc', 1),
      'access callback' => 'usertwiks_edit_access',
      'weight' => 0,
      //'position' =>'right',
      'access arguments' => array(1),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,

   );

   $items['user/%user/edit/account'] = array(
   'title' => 'Аккаунт',
   'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,

   );

  return $items;
}

/*
*  user profile 
*/
function usertwiks_form_soc($form, &$form_state){ 

   $form['#tree'] = True;

   $form['messages'] = array(
     '#markup' => '<div class="msgset"></div>',  
      '#weight' => -50,
   );

   $form['soc'] = array(
         '#title' => 'Для соц',
         '#type' => 'fieldset',
         '#collapsible' => TRUE,
         '#prefix' => '<div id="soc-ajax">', 
         '#suffix' => '</div>',
   );

   $form['soc']['fb'] = array(
         '#title' => 'Для',
         '#type' => 'fieldset',
         '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        // '#collapsed' => true,
   );
   $form['soc']['fb']['fb_profile'] = array(
         '#title' => 'Ваш<span class="out"><span>',
         '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#default_value' =>'',
         '#attributes' =>  array( 'data-type' => 'fb-inp'),
         '#prefix' => '<div class="main-fld">',

   );

   $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
   $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
         '#type' => 'submit',
         '#value' => 'Сохранить изменения',
         //'#submit' => 'usertwiks_soc_submit',
         '#ajax' => array(
              'callback' => 'usertwiks_soc_ajax_callback',
              'wrapper' => 'usertwiks-form-soc',
              'effect' => 'fade',
         ),
   );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'usertwiks_soc_submit';
   // $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'usertwiks_soc_validate';
  $form['#validate'][] = 'usertwiks_soc_validate';

    // if (!empty($_POST) && form_get_errors()) {
     //    drupal_set_message(t('The settings have not been saved because of the errors.'), 'error');
    //  }
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Form validation handler for user_profile_form().
 * @see usertwiks_form_soc_validate
 */
function usertwiks_soc_validate($form, &$form_state){

    $values = $form_state['values'];
    dsm($form_state['value']);
    drupal_set_message('Изменения ');

    if (empty($values['soc']['fb']['fb_profile'])) {
      form_set_error('soc][fb][fb_profile', "пусто");
    }

}

function usertwiks_soc_submit($form, &$form_state){

     $values = $form_state['values'];
   // dsm($values);
    if($values['op']=='Сохранить изменения') {
       drupal_set_message('Изменения сохранены');
    }

   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/*
*  calback для аякса 
*/
function usertwiks_soc_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

  if(form_get_errors()){
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

}else{
  drupal_get_messages();
  drupal_process_form($form['#form_id'], $form, $form_state);

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Drupal есть два способа использования Ajax это:

1. form Ajax - использование в элементе формы '#ajax'
2. Ajax commands - как правило используется для создания ajax ссылок.

Вы выбрали первый вариант, в нём ajax callback должен быть вида:

```
function usertwiks_soc_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['element'];
}
```

Вся же логика изменений прописывается в самой функции формы, где нужное событие отлавливается по изменению $form_state['triggering_element'].
Использование же логики в ajax callback не желательно и приводит к последствиям, вам пришлось заново прогонять drupal_process_form() что мягко говоря не корректно.

Опять же для вывода системных сообщений используется функция drupal_set_message();

А для названия функции валидации и сабмита формы лучше использовать названия с соответствующим суффиксом, для функции usertwiks_form_soc это будут:

- usertwiks_form_soc_validate()
- usertwiks_form_soc_submit()

Так как именно их друпал ищет в первую очередь и они будут подхватываться автоматически.

Comment: Добрый ltm? надо будет попробовать изменить.правда  у вас чуть не так function usertwiks_soc_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state $element) {
  return $form['element'];
}

Comment: блин не увидел очепятки. Добрый день